# Android:Google map v2 draw dragable circle

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to draw circle of some radius on some given location that can be dragged to some other point on map 
I can well draw circle like this

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(circleLocation).radius(10).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.RED));
```

Now I need to drag this circle on map in such a way that when I click on this circle map gets locked and on moving my finger this circle should move on circle and not map itself

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Checkout this library: https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do with shapes but one alternative is to use a marker. It doesn't have the exact result as the marker is drawn flush to the screen view rather than flush to the map but it does have built in drag support. You would need to create a circle image.

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(MELBOURNE)
         .title("Melbourne")
         .draggable(true)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.circle)));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a `View` above the `SupportMapFragment`
2. Add `OnTouchListener` to this `View`
3. Detect if user pressed inside the circle on DOWN event. You will have to use a combination of `Projection` to convert x,y to `LatLng` and `Location.distanceBeetween`
4. If user didn't press inside circle, return `false` to give map chance to handle event
5. If user pressed inside circle, return `true` and save relevant variables
6. On MOVE event continue to use `Projection` to calculate new center based on initial and new x,y

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to draw circle above map,

```
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
    .radius(1000)); // In meters

// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

And GoogleMap doesn't have a touch listener, so you'll have to override onTouchEvent for the parent view of your MapFragment to drag your circle around.